# How to return multiple View object on a View method using Android

Tags: java, android, design-patterns

I have this Adapter that displays custom listview to my layout:

```
    public class AttendedBaseAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DashboardListing> {

    private List<DashboardListing> items;
    private Activity activity;
    private static View v, vDashboard;

    public AttendedBaseAdapter(Activity a, int textViewResourceId, List<DashboardListing> items){
        super(a, textViewResourceId, items);
        activity = a;
        this.items = items;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        v = convertView;
        vDashboard = convertView;

        final DashboardListing attended = items.get(position);


        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row_attended, parent, false);

        LayoutInflater viDashboard = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        vDashboard = viDashboard.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, parent, false);

        SmartImageView imgVenue = (SmartImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.event_poster_url);
        imgVenue.setImageUrl(attended.getPoster());


        TextView txtEventName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.event_name);
        TextView txtVenueName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.event_venue_name);

        txtEventName.setText(attended.getName());
        txtVenueName.setText(attended.getVenue());

        TextView txtAttendedCount = (TextView) vDashboard.findViewById(R.id.txt_attended_count);

        txtAttendedCount.setText("100");


        return v;
    }

}
```

In this part of method getView(...):

```
@Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        v = convertView;
        vDashboard = convertView;

        final DashboardListing attended = items.get(position);


        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row_attended, parent, false);

        LayoutInflater viDashboard = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        vDashboard = viDashboard.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, parent, false);

        SmartImageView imgVenue = (SmartImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.event_poster_url);
        imgVenue.setImageUrl(attended.getPoster());


        TextView txtEventName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.event_name);
        TextView txtVenueName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.event_venue_name);

        txtEventName.setText(attended.getName());
        txtVenueName.setText(attended.getVenue());

        TextView txtAttendedCount = (TextView) vDashboard.findViewById(R.id.txt_attended_count);

        txtAttendedCount.setText("100");


        return v;
    }
```

How can I return multple(not just the View **v** but I also want to return the View **vDashboard**? because I have 2 layouts View v refers to **R.layout.row_attended** and View vDashboard refers to **R.layout.fragment_dashboard**

Comment: It's the adapter of a listview right? Well, you should only return the View of the item row...

Comment: @MarcoAcierno Yes, it's for a ListView but I want to reuse the AttendedBaseAdapter so I will not request again to the server. And also I indicated two View for two different layout

Answer (score 0):

> How can I return multple(not just the View v but I also want to return the View vDashboard?

You would need to wrap them in some sort of container (e.g., `LinearLayout`) with rules for how they should be sized and positioned within that container, then return the container from `getView()`.

Even easier would be to combine the layout files, directly or using `<include>` elements, so that you only are inflating one layout.

In other words, `getView()` returns the *one* `View` that is to be the `ListView` row (or `GridView` cell or whatever) for the given `position`. That `View` can be a `ViewGroup` populated by whatever you want, so long as it meets your UI requirements.